# Issues with changing orientation of an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios6, avfoundation, calayer, avcapturesession, autorotate

I'm using AVFoundation to create a video camera UI.  The containing viewcontroller will only be displayed in LandscapeRight orientation.  When changing the output orientation via the preview layer, it displays correctly:

```
self.previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.captureSession];
self.previewLayer.orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
[self.displayContainer.layer addSublayer:self.previewLayer];
```

However, I realize that the orientation property of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is deprecated in favor of AVCaptureConnection.videoOrientation.  When using that instead:

```
    self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

The preview layer doesn't appear to change orientation at all, even when trying different options for the orientation.  Is there another step I am missing in order to do this the recommended way?

EDIT:

Below are the autorotate methods present in the view controller:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

SOLUTION:

This is solved both by apply all of the advice in @Spectravideo328's answer, and by adding the preview layer on to the ViewControllers view layer, as opposed to the displayContainer  subview.

Comment: Please see updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not an AvCaptureVideoPreviewLayer issue but rather a CALayer issue in general (which previewLayer is a subclass of).

All CALayers needs their frames set: in your case, I would just add to your code:

```
self.previewlayer.frame=self.view.bounds.
```

It is critical that you use self.view.bounds and not self.view.frame so that the previewlayer dimensions rotate (adjust) if the device is rotated.

Hope this helps.

Update:
This is from the supportedInterfaceOrientations help description:

> When the user changes the device orientation, the system calls this method on the root view controller or the topmost presented view controller that fills the window. If the view controller supports the new orientation, the window and view controller are rotated to the new orientation. This method is only called if the view controller’s shouldAutorotate method returns YES.

Update your shouldAutorotate to always return YES.

Comment: Thank you for the note on bounds vs. frames, I was not aware of that distinction.  However, this doesn't resolve the issue.  No matter what orientation value I used, the preview layer seems to remain unchanged.

Comment: @Chris, I think there are a couple of other places where this could be a problem. Let's start with this:Do you have shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in your VC to let the VC know what orientations are accepted?

Comment: Changed it to YES, but this had no effect.

Comment: Please change self.displayContainer.layer to self.view.layer

Comment: Please note: this code ONLY works if called outside viewDidLoad (just spent ages trying to work out why correct code failed. Apple gives views a "half initialized" bounds during viewDidLoad)